# Why Updating From Database Does Not Bring All Tables from the Database?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

When I update the model from database, I am not able to access to some of the tables as entity.
Through `Model Browser`, I can see those tables under `MyDBEntities.Store` (I don't know what it is) but under the `Entity Types`, these tables are not listed. Tried to downgrade to EF5, tried opening and updating the model with VS2012. Tried deleting and recreating the model so many times but no luck. If I right click on `Entity Folder` and select `Add New Entity`, under the `Base Types`, these tables are not listed either.  All tables have PK and FK by the way. Anyone has a clue?

EDIT:

I just noticed, if remove the model and while updating it from database, if only add these 5 tables, they are being added properly. But this time caused the run-time error: `Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns.`

Comment: Not much code really. Trying to create the model.

Comment: Perhaps show a screenshot of your model then.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an association table that creates M:N relation between two other tables and has no additional attributes, then the association table is not shown in the model.

See http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/.